# Tomcat memory leak and destroy because of dubbo,how to resolve this problem

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks

```
Dec 11, 2018 5:18:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Dec 11, 2018 5:18:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 11, 2018 5:18:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15263 ms
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [DubboRegistryFailedRetryTimer-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(mservice01:2181)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [DubboSaveRegistryCache-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [DubboClientReconnectTimer-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O client worker #1-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [dubbo-remoting-client-heartbeat-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [DubboClientReconnectTimer-thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O client worker #1-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [dubbo-remoting-client-heartbeat-thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [DubboResponseTimeoutScanTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [New I/O client worker #1-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [DubboSharedHandler-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [DubboSharedHandler-thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@42465293]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@7bfceccd]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@1142734a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@432a0c42]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@5fac0a6e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@3d17d7ab]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@3fcd3b60]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@2c1678c7]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@1356f851]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@10ffcf1f]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@463ff05b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@5970681b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@7dc09714]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@13293884]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@2a2dbf92]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@70473a7c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal `enter code here`with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@9c67b57]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@53f19ff3]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@14676b30]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@5dba271a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@671cf339]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@38cde62e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@17dc34ec]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@1bd243fa]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@1b57ee82]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@4cfc9750]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@3a71a177]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@33b5f850]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@17b2235a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@3fdc70eb]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@811147e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext$1@7d45ffe7]) and a value of type [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext] (value [com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcContext@14fa0a54]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@61e0672f]) and a value of type [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest] (value [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest@12d45362]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@9d26a8f]) and a value of type [httl.Context] (value [httl.Context@4e5332fb]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

.......... and many ,I can not post all because of the limit


INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooTrace.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1813)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1128)

Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1813)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:154)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:853)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.error(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:576)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$1.uncaughtException(ClientCnxn.java:414)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1959)


Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "localhost-startStop-1-SendThread(mservice01:2181)"
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Dec 11, 2018 6:01:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
```

that's all,I use dubbo and deploy to tomcat,but it's logs show like that,and destroy.How to resolve this problem,please help.My English is not goods,I holp you can know~

Comment: It seems that your app is lack of a jar file. Ensure that you have import all the jar file you want to use.

Comment: I think I add all I need,the application can run normally ,It suddenly happends in a long time running